# is this the correct way to have ur CoreData NSFetchedResults and NSPersistentStore function?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been trying to load my pre-filled database into my device, ive tried copying the database from the simulator directory and placing it into my application folder, but it doesnt work, so i was wondering weather is my NSFetchedResultsController fetching properly?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }

    CoreDataMelakaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CoreDataMelakaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WhereTo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
   // [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

PersistenStore

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataMelaka.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

i've replace the persistentStore with this, and now how ever i delete the database or the app from the simulator, it appears with 2 data, which i installed the first time i tried this method.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataMelaka.sqlite"];

    NSString *storePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreDataMelaka" ofType:@"sqlite"];


    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataMelaka.sqlite"]; 

    NSLog(@"store URL %@", storeURL);

    // Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
        NSLog(@"proceed");
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreDataMelaka" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"doesnt exist");
        NSLog(@"defalultStorePath %@", defaultStorePath);


        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:writableDBPath error:NULL];
            NSLog(@"storePath= %@", storePath);
        }
    }    

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

Comment: Is your pre-filled database created by CoreData or have you created it yourself?

Comment: i use the simulator to create a pre-filled database using the core data. its stored in the simulator, but when i copy that particular database and paste it to the application folder, it create another new database in the simulator which is empty and reads that instead of the 1 in the application folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NSFetchedResultsController looks like the standard auto-generated code. It should be fetching correctly, but I would need to know more about your code to be 100% sure.

I would guess that the problem has to do with finding the database. Are you sure you are putting it in the documents directory? I'm assuming that you have copied your database into Xcode and it's copying your database into your app. If this is the case, you database is not going to be in your Documents directory. You can download your app files using the Device section of the Organizer in Xcode to confirm this. Your database is being copied into your main bundle and you need to extract it from there. Here's some code that does just that:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;

    NSError * error = nil;
    NSURL * storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager new];

    // !!!: Be sure to create a new default database if the MOM file is ever changed.

    // If there is no previous database, then a default one is used.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {

        NSURL * defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DefaultStore.sqlite" 
                                                          withExtension:nil];

        // Copies the default database from the main bundle to the documents directory.
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL
                             toURL:storeURL
                             error:&error];

        if (error) {

            // Handle error here.

            // Resets the error.
            error = nil;
        }
    }

    [fileManager release];

    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    [__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                           configuration:nil 
                                                     URL:storeURL 
                                                 options:nil 
                                                   error:&error];
    if (error) {

        // Handle error here.

        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

To find this and other Core Data conveniences, check out [RBCoreDataAdditions](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBCoreDataAdditions).

Comment: Yeap, im getting the database from user/library/application support/iphone simulator/4.3.2/applications/<some integers>/Documents..
i dont understand the file download part, using the Device part, izzit once i've connected the device, at the organizer section, i download it manually from a directory? how if i uploaded this to the apps store, the database wont follow rite?

Comment: You may be copying it from the Documents on the simulator, but when you copy it into an app via Xcode, it goes into the main bundle. To download your files from your device open the Organizer, select the Devices tab, select Applications under your device, select your application, then select download. I'm using Xcode 4, by the way. Once you download the files, you should see that your default database is in the main bundle. By putting the database in the main bundle, it will be uploaded to the app store. If this isn't what you want, then you need to remove it before archiving.

Comment: You may find that you have a database in your Documents directory, but it should be an empty database that Core Data created for you. You can open it up and run a few queries to confirm this.

Comment: aha. So using the organizer is the way to build a pre-filled database. I'll get to that first thing tomorrow. Ive seen that method on the WWDC video. Thanks. Hope it works haha

Comment: WWDC 2011 session 317 goes over the Organizer in detail. Also, if you create a bundle for your database, you need to change the above code to go to that bundle rather than the main bundle.

Comment: i didnt create any bundle for the database, just simply dragging and dropping into the main application folder. Ill try the WWDC method first thing tomorrow morning, its 3.15am over here in Malaysia now. ahah